# Need a sample script to perform an automated action on a Cisco router via ZOC SSH

Tags: router, terminal, script, automation

Does anymone show me a script sample using the software ["ZOC Terminal"](http://www.emtec.com/zoc/index.html) (version 6.2) to perform an simple automatic action on a router, let's say a reboot or change of daylight savings time or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REXX script:

```
/* REXX: reboot.zrx */
connectip= "192.168.1.1"
connectname= "ROUTERNAME"
connectpassword= "telnetpassword"
enablepassword= "enablepass"
CALL rebootrouter
EXIT

rebootrouter:
CALL ZocConnect connectip
CALL ZocWait "Password:"
CALL ZocSend connectpassword||"^M"
CALL ZocWait ">"
CALL ZocSend "enable^M"
CALL ZocWait "Password:"
CALL ZocSend enablepassword||"^M"
CALL ZocWait "#"
CALL ZocSend "reload"
CALL ZocWait "]"
CALL ZocSend "y^M"
CALL ZocWait "]"
CALL ZocSend "y^M"
RETURN
```

(Shamelessly stol.. umm borrowed from [here](http://episteme.arstechnica.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/469092836/m/769004844831) and posted with a few beautifications)

Comment: From user [Duane Richards](http://superuser.com/users/562304/duane-richards):  This also works in ZOC version 7.06.1.

Answer (score 0):

While this sounds like a question for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), I've used [Expect](http://expect.nist.gov/) to do things like this in the past.